# react native onesignal android push token is null

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal

I'm using [react-native-onesignal](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal) and I'm getting push token is null.
[image]

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const { currentState } = AppState


    OneSignal.init(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
    OneSignal.configure();

    OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived)
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened)
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds)
}
    onReceived = (notification) => {
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification)
}

onOpened = (openResult) => {
    console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body)
    console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData)
    console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus)
    console.log('openResult: ', openResult)
}

onIds = (device) => {
    console.log('Device info: ', device)
}
```

in addition in onesignal website under users I get the error google play services library error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace ONESIGNAL_APP_ID with the app id from your onesignal account (can be found in settings -> keys & id's tab after logging in to onesignal account)

Comment: I have the same issue, although I've replaced ONESIGNAL_APP_ID with the actual one